# Proof that $E[\langle X_1, X_2 \rangle_{L^2}] = 0$

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, expected-value

Given is the following lemma

> If the random variables $X_1, X_2 \in L^2([0,1])$ are independent, $E[\|X_i\|_{L^2}^2] <
>  \infty$ with $i = 1,2$ and $E[X_1] = 0$, then $$E[ \langle X_1, X_2
>  \rangle_{L^2} ] = E \left[\int\limits_0^1 X_1X_2 \right] = 0$$

My idea for the proof is:
$E[\langle X_1, X_2 \rangle_{L^2}] = E[\langle X_2, X_1 \rangle_{L^2}] = \langle X_2, E[X_1] \rangle_{L^2} = \langle X_2, 0 \rangle_{L^2} = 0$.

Now I asked a friend of mine who told me that the "basic idea" behind this is true, but that the above expression is not defined. I have to work with conditional expectation and iterated expectations. But I don't get it. Why do I need these two results and what is the correct proof then? Thanks!

Comment: I can mistaken, but for me it's just Fubini $$\mathbb E\int_0^1X_1X_2=\int_0^1\mathbb E[X_1X_2],$$ and since the $X_i$ are independent, $\mathbb E[X_1X_2]=\mathbb E[X_1]\mathbb E[X_2]=0.$

Comment: Please clarify the symbols in your questions: $X_1,X_2$ are random variables or stochastic processes(martingales);  what $\langle \cdots\rangle_{L_2}$ means, inner product or quadratic covariance?